# Wordpress website Malware : How to remove it?

Tags: wordpress, malware

My wordpress website contains a malicious code (malware) .i had scanned it using sucuri online site test . How can i remove it ?

Comment: more information about the result of the malware scan, pls.

Answer (score 1):

I've used something like: `grep -Rl "eval"` . and `grep -Rl "base64"` . it can be a good start.

Try to search for patterns in the infected files with your SHELL.

Comment: Alright .. But what are major files that can be infected ?

Comment: Maybe all.. maybe only plugins or theme files.

Answer (score 0):

Follow These Steps:-

```
1) Install Sucuri Plugin
2) Scan Your Site
3) Check Core File Integrity
4) Check Recently Modified Files
5) Confirm User Logins
```